# AudioManager Declaration Crashes Android App

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

Greetings,

I'm having a bit of trouble with an Android app that I'm working on (mostly for practice and learning purposes) that uses the `AudioManager` object.  When defining the `AudioManager` as follows, however, the app crashes when I run it:

```
//Import the AudioManager
import android.media.AudioManager;

public class RingtoneModeChanger extends Activity {

    //Causes crash:
    public AudioManager mManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    /* Code for the rest of the app... */
}
```

When I simply comment out the AudioManager declaration, the app does not crash.  Any ideas as far as what I'm doing wrong? I'm a bit of a beginner to Android development, so I have a feeling that I'm missing something obvious.

I've also tried adding the `android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` and `android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permissions to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, but that has made no difference.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Does the app throw an exception? Have you looked at the adb log?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out; you can't access system services before the `onCreate()` method.  So, I simply had to declare the object of `AudioManager`  within `onCreate()`.  Thanks anyway!